# Generate Entity Framework code for SQL Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

This is weird but is it possible to generate c# EF code from existing database to insert data, Similar to generating data scripts from SQL Server?

Instead of raw SQL, I want to generate code which uses EF models to insert data.
Something like

```
            var testData1 = new TestData
            {
                CreatorUserId = 1,
                Name = "Test",
                Description = "Autogenerated.",
                CountryCode = "IND"
            };
```

Comment: have you looked at DB first approach of EF ?

Comment: Hi @EhsanUllahNazir, I don't just want EF models, I want data as well :)

Comment: You can generate any code in C# EF. You can generate expression if queries are all you need.

Comment: @FilipCordas I am creating a feature to insert test data. This is similar to adding seed data in EF. But in my case, I have SQL file available for test and ids are hardcoded. So, I want to migrate all the SQL to c# EF code in easy way :)

Comment: If you already have your SQL, why not use it directly? Like Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()

Comment: Hi @MaximZabolotskikh, I can use the sql directly and it works fine but the SQL code has primary keys and foreign keys hardcoded. It will only work once.

Comment: I personally don't think there is sth out of the box for it. I'd write my custom parser that will go through insert statements from your file and make objects from the values.

Comment: You should be able to rerun the script. You may need to reseed the identity columns and/or turn IDENTITY_INSERT on. Much easier than the alternative IMO.

Comment: Hi @SteveGreene, that won't help. SQL server won't allow 2 records with same primary key :D

Comment: I got it working using string manipulation but I am not proud of that :/